# Скорость работы сравнения Date

Tags: javascript

Возник вопрос по сравнению дат.

Сделал [тесты](https://jsperf.com/dates-vs-string-comparison/1). `getTime` победил. Тесты делались в Chrome v76.

Соответственно вопросы.

- Почему сравнение непосредственно дат происходит так медленно?
- Почему `valueOf` работает медленнее, чем `getTime`?

Код, используемый для теста

```js
const d1 = new Date('2019-09-02T11:50:32.473Z');
const d2 = new Date('2019-09-03T11:50:32.474Z');
let r;

console.time('date');
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if (d1 > d2) {
    r = true;
  } else {
    r = false;
  }
}
console.timeEnd('date');


console.time('getTime');
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
    r = true;
  } else {
    r = false;
  }
}
console.timeEnd('getTime');

console.time('valueOf');
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if (d1.valueOf() > d2.valueOf()) {
    r = true;
  } else {
    r = false;
  }
}
console.timeEnd('valueOf');
```

**UPD**

Интересует время работы в *node.js*.

Результаты выполнения тестов:

date: 141.500ms

getTime: 2.147ms

valueOf: 7.896ms

Comment: а как вообще можно сравнивать просто объекты ? if (d1 > d2) {} - как минимум странно

Comment: @СергейПетрашко а что в этом странного? :-) Даты как объекты можно и нужно сравнивать! Кроме `==` и `===`.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, даты как раз можно так сравнивать - у них перегружен внутренний метод `ToPrimitive` поэтому сравниваются значения а не ссылки

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, если смотреть спецификацию то и [`valueOf`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.valueof) и [`getTime`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.gettime) - делают одно и то же, следовательно разница может быть либо в реализации в конкретном браузере, либо в не совсем корректных тестах

Comment: например в EDGE - valueOf - быстрее

Comment: а, например, в таком [тесте](https://jsperf.com/dates-vs-string-comparison/4) результаты вполне сравнимые

Comment: @Grundy верно, согласно спецификации `valueOf` и `getTime` делают одно и то же. Насколько я понимаю, `ToPrimitive` вызывает `valueOf`. Почему явный вызов `valueOf` быстрее? В Вашем тесте, в хроме v76 результаты не совсем сравнимые - сравнение объектов в 2-3 раза медленнее.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, сравнение объектов медленнее просто потому что больше действий выполняется, если смотреть ту же спецификацию. При это значения для valueOf и getTime почти не отличаются

Comment: @Grundy Согласно спецификации в методе `ToPrimitive` один `if`, вызов `OrdinaryToPrimitive` и еще один `if`, потом уже вызов `valueOf`. Два `if` и один вызов функции могут привести к 10 кратной потери производительности?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, во-первых, почему нет? во-вторых, в зависимости от теста - "производительность" может как теряться так и почти не меняться.

Comment: @Grundy Почему нет? Потому что это контринтуитивно)) У вас есть кейс, в котором почти "производительность" не меняется? В приведенном вами тесте, разница в 2-3 раза есть.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, там же на графике есть - 76 версия - почти одинаково, никаких двух-трех раз нет

Comment: @Grundy http://prntscr.com/p1k63y - 76 версия хрома.

Comment: Тестировщики) Не забывайте про кеширование результатов функции в движке)) Не нужно сравнивать одни и те же даты, берите каждый раз новые. Вычитайте из результата случай когда просто берутся новые даты, то есть без их сравнения.